# What is the most efficient way to swap the values from 2 arrays matching a replacement key in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

The first array defines the current values:

```
Array ( [0] => schools [1] => high-wood [2] => students )
```

The second array is a map that is triggered by the first array and also hold the replacement keys:

```
Array ( [/schools/{school-name}/students/] => /{school-name}/students/ )
```

The idea is that the second segment of the array key holds the replacement key and the final returned array is the output map indicating the place of the replacement key.

The final desired output would then be:

```
/high-wood/students/
```

I am trying to find a generic solution to this that may have any number of incoming values, and any number of replacement keys in any position.

Here is an example of the generic incoming array:

```
Array ( [0] => param1 [1] => param2 [2] => key-value )
```

And the generic-ish map:

```
Array ( [/param1/param2/{key-map}/] => /{map-key}/anything/ )
```

The output of this would be:

```
/key-value/anything/
```

The basic idea is that the map-key is detected at the second segment (it could be anywhere), so that value is taken from the incoming array and put into the map-key holder of the output array.

Currently I have managed to make a vomitus array of foreach loops and preg_matches and I fear even presenting those would further confuse the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...how about something like this.  Untested:

```
$input  = array('schools', 'high-wood', 'students');

// Here I'm making the blithe assumption that you can further tweak the URI map
$uriMap = array('^/schools/([^/]+)/students/$' => '/{school-name}/students/');
//               ^         ^^^^^^^          ^
//             anchor    capturing group   anchor

// Massage input to match format of $uriMap
$inUri  = '/'.implode('/', $input).'/';

foreach($uriMap as $pattern => $target){
    if(false !== preg_match($pattern, $inUri, $matches){
        // $matches[1] should have the matched string
        $mapped = str_replace('{school-name}', $matches[1], $target);
        break;
    }
}

echo $mapped;
```

> /high-wood/students/

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I expanded on my original question so it is a bit more clear that the arrays will all be generic.